# MongoDB Spring Pessimistic Lock

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement a Pessimistic lock on my Spring Boot application running with a MongoDB instance.

The problem:

User A, select the Document ID 123
User A, update the Document, append one field and Save it
User B, select the Document ID 123 and need to wait User A finish the Save.

Is it possible do with MongoDB?!

Comment: I don't know about pessimistic locking but what about doing something like checkout. so user A is going to edit the document, he performs checkout. When checkout is performed the field `checkedOutBy` is populated by `userId` who performed the checkout. Then unless user A finishes his transaction nobody else will be able to perform update.

Comment: @bilak I've found this git repository about [transactions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/transactions) doing the exact same thing you sad. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [post](https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/28/hands-on-mongodb-4-0-transactions-with-spring-data). On my tests, it looks like solve the problem.

But the Best approach is to use WebFlux with Mongo. Unfortunately, it's not possible on the project I'm running at this moment